# Unable to insert into mysqli database from inside paypal ipn listener script

Tags: php, database, mysqli, paypal

SOLVED: See answer below

### HOLD: Reading the latest paypal docs I realise that paypal's procedure has changed considerably since I implemented the script shown below many years ago. I am going through paypal's docs and will modify my script accordingly so please take no action for the moment. Thank you for reading.

I had a perfectly good paypal listener script which was working well with the old mysql in Php5.3.

I upgraded to the mysqli method some time ago but the paypal ipn listener script got missed out from this upgrade. I only noticed this after upgrading from Php5.3 to Php7.1 a few months ago. I recently came round to upgrading this script to mysqli in what I thought would be a 5 minute job (that is, before converting to prepared statements and implementing other security measures). Instead of 5 minutes, 5 days have now gone by and I am still no closer to a solution!

My problem is that the mysqli insert feature is not working inside the listener script. I can take exactly the same code block (both the mysqli connection string and the mysqli insert query) and it will work in a different script - but not inside the ipn listener.

I can even view the listener page in the browser and click on the browser’s refresh button and this will do the mysqli insert using arbitrary data values that I give it! However, the mysqli insert does not work when the script is triggered from paypal following a payment.

I go through the standard sequence:
Receive POST data from paypal after paying with a button in a live environment.
Return exactly the same data, with cmd appended, to paypal for validation.
Receive the VERIFIED validation.

I then attempt to connect to mysqli and insert the POST data into the database.
Finally, I send an email to confirm receipt of the VERIFIED data.

All works well except for the mysqli insert part in the middle.

Since the same mysqli code block works inside a different script I cannot for the life of me think where the problem lies. I have obviously tried many different permutations and combinations (such as varying the location of the closing curly brackets), but to no avail.

I wonder if someone with an eagle eye can spot the source of the problem? A few similar questions have been asked on s/o in the past but nothing identical to  this. Repeating again, I thought this was going to be a very simple 5 minute job, changing a few lines of mysql to mysqli!

Edit #1: I changed the subject string of my 'if verified' mail from 'VERIFIED IPN' to 'VERIFIED IPN TEST' just to give a perturbation to investigate why mail was coming through as verified yet mysqli insert was failing. The result was that the verified mail stopped coming through! I later changed subject string back to as before but mail did not resume. So it appears the problem is deeper than merely mysqli insert failing. I wonder if paypal still supports the fsockopen / $header method of checking verification.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//error_reporting(E_STRICT);/*This throws up nothing spurious*/

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
/*Now loop through the incoming $_POST array*/
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";/*& sign denotes 'by reference' (see 4Tsale.php)*/
}

$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$mc_gross = htmlentities($_POST['mc_gross']);//Repeat htmlentities
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$protection_eligibility = $_POST['protection_eligibility'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
//etc

if (!$fp) {
//echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} 
else {  
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp))
{
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
$res = trim($res); 
}//while

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
{
$link = mysqli_connect('servername', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
//printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
mail($mail_To, "Mysql Connect failed", $mail_From);
exit();
}
else {
//echo "Connected OK!<br />";
mail($mail_To, "Mysql Connect succeeded", $mail_From);
}

$query_stmt1 = "INSERT INTO paypal_ipns (mail_Subject, mc_gross, invoice, protection_eligibility, payer_id, tax, payment_date, payment_status, first_name, option_selection1, option_selection2, mc_fee, custom, payer_status,  business, verify_sign, payer_email, option_name1, option_name2, txn_id, payment_type, payer_business_name, btn_id, last_name, receiver_email, receiver_id, txn_type, mc_currency, residence_country, req) 
VALUES('$mail_Subject', '$mc_gross', '$invoice', '$protection_eligibility', '$payer_id', '$tax', '$payment_date', '$payment_status', '$first_name', '$option_selection1', '$option_selection2', '$mc_fee', '$custom', '$payer_status', '$business', '$verify_sign', '$payer_email', '$option_name1', '$option_name2', '$txn_id', '$payment_type', '$payer_business_name', '$btn_id', '$last_name', '$receiver_email', '$receiver_id', '$txn_type', '$mc_currency', '$residence_country', '$req')";

if (mysqli_query($link, $query_stmt1)) 
{
echo "New record created successfully<br>";
}  else {
echo "Error: " . $query_stmt1 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);

$mail_From = "From: sale@mybiz.com";
$mail_To = "xxx@yahoo.co.uk";
$mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
$mail_Body = $req;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $emailtext . "\n\n" . $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}//if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)

else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) 
{
$mail_From = "From: sale@mybiz.com";
$mail_To = "xxx@yahoo.co.uk";
$mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
$mail_Body = $req;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}

}//if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0). Tried locating above as well

//}//while tried here as well

fclose ($fp);//Tried locating these 2 lines above as well
}//if (!$fp). Ditto

?>
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about BBoM and spaghetti code? In terms of code style and good practices, your code looks just terrible. I advise you to read some articles about Design Patterns, about MVC, ORM, DRY, KISS and SOLID. Read what is refactoring and how to apply it to make your code better.

Comment: Many thanks. Will study these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was modifying a version of the ipn listener script that was not registered as the notification url with Paypal. Both versions had almost identical, long-winded names with the php file containing 4 underscores, the differentiating factor between the two being just 2 letters at the end before the .php extension. This error cost me almost a week's lost time for what was essentially a 5 minute job! Also, I should have looked at the ipn history in paypal earlier. It was a classic case of losing the wood for the trees. Trying to find the cause of the problem by sifting not just through the trees but the branches, when I had in effect wandered into the wrong forest! I have now noted the urls for both the ipn listener notification and the merchant return page specified in the button definition at the top of the script as an aide memoire. Hope this helps someone.